# PHP entity class generator

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am creating entity (of entity-view-controller)(in other words, model of MVC) classes which theoreticlly match the databse table I have. Is there a tool which reads mysql table and creates a model class code? (NOT on execution, a code output is required) 
 I expect an output like

```
class{
public $columnname1;
public $columnname2;
public $columnname3;
public $columnname4;
public $columnname5;
public $columnname6;
function __construct(&$columnname1, &$columnname2){...}
function insert(&$columnname1, &$columnname2){}
function delete(&$columnname1){}
...
}
```

A tool which would also create insert,update and delete by id functions would help me a lot.

The tool may be free or paid.

Comment: There is something the other way round, checkout [RedBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/). And also there is [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) which is similar, however there is [propel](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html), which might be what you're looking for: [Existing Databases](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases).

Comment: This may be interesting: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php. But the feature is still EXPERIMENTAL.

Comment: @mogria I expect an exported text file (php or whatever) as an output

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you approach it the other way around: first design your model, and then your data-access and database tables should be based on model.

Comment: @NazarMerza what makes that more than a personal preference?

Comment: @Ugur, if your purpose is to learn, and not confrontation, then I am willing to teach you why it is not a personal preference.

Comment: @NazarMerza yes please do tell me

Comment: @Ugur using an ORM is not only personal preference. An ORM maps a high level description into a low level description. The ORM's input includes e.g. relational or domain information, while the low level description does not. The code generated by the ORM is more or less boiler-plate code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448684/why-should-you-use-an-orm

Comment: @Ugur If you have an existing database, which you can't change, your question might make sense. But even then, remapping the database's structure to an ORM's description would be a good idea.

Comment: Any idea on implementing same functionality using Codeigniter instead of ORM ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<s>PDO can **[fetch results into an object](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)**.</s>

Design a class which matches your database/query structure, and use `PDO::FETCH_INTO` to fetch the result set into an already instantiated object. Misread the question, my bad.

---

To generate the class itself from the database structure, there are several projects (I haven't tested, but this came up on a very simple search).

- [db2php](http://code.google.com/p/db2php/)
- [PHP MySQL class generator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2802-PHP-Generate-classes-to-manipulate-MySQL-table-rows.html)

Comment: I am looking for a solution which does that automatically, because it can be done automatically. I know how to do all of these, like knowing math and buying a calculator

Comment: Wait, you want to generate the class from the table?

Comment: Yes , like stated in the question

Comment: I was using netbeans, I think I'll try db2php now, looks useful

Comment: PHP MySQL class generator is not compatible with php 8

Answer (score 10):

The following code is what I've used for a long time to create PHP models for MySQL and DB2 tables.  I've got stubs in place for MSSQL, PGSQL and SQLite but have never needed to complete them.

Here's the code generator class:

```
<?php
/**
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT The MIT License
 * @version 1.0.0_20130220000000
 */

/**
 * This class will generate PHP source code for a "model" that interfaces with 
 * a database table.
 * 
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT The MIT License
 * @version 1.0.0_20130220000000
 */
class db_code_generator{
    private $closing_tag;
    private $columns;
    private $database;
    private $host;
    private $password;
    private $port;
    private $table;
    private $type;
    private $username;

    /**
     * Constructor. By default we will try to connect to a MySQL database on 
     * localhost.
     * 
     * @param string $database The name of the database the user wants to connect
     * to.
     * 
     * @param string $table The name of the table to generate code for.
     * 
     * @param string $username The username we should use to connect to the 
     * database.
     * 
     * @param string $password The password we need to connect to the database.
     * 
     * @param string $host The host or server we will try to connect to. If the 
     * user doesn't give us a host we default to localhost.
     * 
     * @param string $port The port we should try to connect to. Typically this 
     * will not be passed so we default to NULL.
     * 
     * @param string $type The type of database we are connecting to. Valid 
     * values are: db2, mssql, mysql, pgsql, sqlite.
     */
    public function __construct($database = NULL,
                                         $table = NULL,
                                         $username = NULL,
                                         $password = NULL,
                                         $host = 'localhost',
                                         $type = 'mysql',
                                         $port = NULL,
                                         $closing_tag = TRUE){
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->closing_tag = $closing_tag;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code for a model that represents a record in a table.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code generated for this model.
     */
    public function get_code(){
        $this->get_data_definition();
        $code = $this->get_file_head();
        $code .= $this->get_properties();
        $code .= $this->get_ctor();
        $code .= $this->get_dtor();
        $code .= $this->get_method_stubs();
        $code .= $this->get_file_foot();
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Create the code needed for the __construct function.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for the __construct function.
     */
    private function get_ctor(){
        $code = "\t/**\n";
        $code .= "\t * Constructor.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param mixed \$id The unique id for a record in this table. Defaults to NULL\n";
        if ('db2' === $this->type){
            $code .= "\n\t * @param string \$library The library where the physical file resides. Defaults to LIBRARY\n";
        }
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @see base_$this->type::__construct\n";
        $code .= "\t */\n";
        if ('db2' === $this->type){
            $code .= "\tpublic function __construct(\$id = NULL, \$library = 'LIBRARY'){\n";
            $code .= "\t\tparent::__construct(\$id, \$library);\n";
        }else{
            $code .= "\tpublic function __construct(\$id = NULL){\n";
            $code .= "\t\tparent::__construct(\$id);\n";
        }
        $code .= "\t}\n\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Connect to the requested database and get the data definition for the
     * requested table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition(){
        try{
            switch ($this->type){
                case 'db2':
                    $this->get_data_definition_db2();
                    break;
                case 'mssql':
                    $this->get_data_definition_mssql();
                    break;
                case 'mysql':
                    $this->get_data_definition_mysql();
                    break;
                case 'pgsql':
                    $this->get_data_definition_pgsql();
                    break;
                case 'sqlite':
                    $this->get_data_definition_sqlite();
                    break;
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get data definition information for a DB2 table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition_db2(){
        $con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$this->host;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $this->username, $this->password);
        $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_SIZE, COLUMN_TEXT, DECIMAL_DIGITS, ORDINAL_POSITION, TYPE_NAME FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = '". strtoupper($this->database) ."' AND TABLE_NAME = '". strtoupper($this->table) ."'";
        $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
        if ($statement->execute()){
            while ($row = $statement->fetch()){
                if (NULL !== $row['DECIMAL_DIGITS']){
                    $decimal = $row['DECIMAL_DIGITS'];
                }else{
                    $decimal = NULL;
                }
                if ('DECIMAL' === $row['TYPE_NAME'] && NULL !== $row['DECIMAL_DIGITS'] && '0' !== $row['DECIMAL_DIGITS']){
                    $type = 'float';
                }else if ('DECIMAL' === $row['TYPE_NAME']){
                    $type = 'integer';
                }else{
                    $type = strtolower($row['TYPE_NAME']);
                }
                if ('1' === $row['ORDINAL_POSITION']){
                    $key = 'PRI';
                }else{
                    $key = NULL;
                }
                $this->columns[$row['COLUMN_NAME']] = array('allow_null' => TRUE,
                                                                          'decimal' => $decimal,
                                                                          'default' => NULL,
                                                                          'extra' => NULL,
                                                                          'key' => $key,
                                                                          'length' => $row['COLUMN_SIZE'],
                                                                          'name' => $row['COLUMN_NAME'],
                                                                          'text' => $row['COLUMN_TEXT'],
                                                                          'type' => $type);
            }
            ksort($this->columns);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get data definition information for a MS SQL table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition_mssql(){
        return "The code for generating MS SQL models is not yet implemented.\n";
    }

    /**
     * Get data definition information for a MySQL table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition_mysql(){
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;";
        if (NULL !== $this->port){
            $dsn .= "port=$this->port;";
        }
        $dsn .= "dbname=$this->database";
        $con = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
        $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $this->table";
        $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
        if ($statement->execute()){
            while ($row = $statement->fetch()){
                $this->columns[$row['Field']] = array('allow_null' => $row['Null'],
                                                                  'decimal' => NULL,
                                                                  'default' => $row['Default'],
                                                                  'extra' => $row['Extra'],
                                                                  'key' => $row['Key'],
                                                                  'length' => NULL,
                                                                  'name' => $row['Field'],
                                                                  'text' => NULL,
                                                                  'type' => $row['Type']);
            }
            ksort($this->columns);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get data definition information for a PostgreSQL table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition_pgsql(){
        return "The code for generating PostgreSQL models is not yet implemented.\n";
    }

    /**
     * Get data definition information for a SQLite table.
     */
    private function get_data_definition_sqlite(){
        return "The code for generating SQLite models is not yet implemented.\n";
    }

    /**
     * Create the code needed for the __destruct function.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for the __destruct function.
     */
    private function get_dtor(){
        $code = "\t/**\n";
        $code .= "\t * Destructor.\n";
        $code .= "\t */\n";
        $code .= "\tpublic function __destruct(){\n";
        $code .= "\t\tparent::__destruct();\n";
        $code .= "\t}\n\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code found at the end of the file - the closing brace, the 
     * ending PHP tag and a new line. Some PHP programmers prefer to not have a 
     * closing PHP tag while others want the closing tag and trailing newline - 
     * it probably just depends on their programming background. Regardless it's 
     * best to let everyone have things the way they want.
     */
    private function get_file_foot(){
        $code = '';
        if ($this->closing_tag){
            $code .= "}\n?>\n";
        }else{
            $code .= '}';
        }
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code found at the beginning of the file - the PHPDocumentor 
     * doc block, the require_once for the correct base class and the class name.
     * 
     * @return string The code generated for the beginning of the file.
     */
    private function get_file_head(){
        $code  = "<?php\n";
        $code .= "/**\n";
        $code .= " * Please enter a description of this class.\n";
        $code .= " *\n";
        $code .= " * @author XXX <XXX@domain.com>\n";
        $code .= " * @copyright Copyright (c) ". date('Y') ."\n";
        $code .= " * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html GPLv3\n";
        $code .= " * @version ". date('Ymd') ."\n";
        $code .= " */\n\n";
        $code .= "require_once('base_$this->type.php');\n\n";
        $code .= "class ". strtolower($this->table) ." extends base_$this->type{\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code for a delete method stub.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for the method stub.
     */
    private function get_method_stub_delete(){
        $code  = "\t/**\n";
        $code .= "\t * Override the delete method found in the base class.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param mixed \$id The unique record ID to be deleted.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @return bool TRUE if a record was successfully deleted from the table, FALSE otherwise.\n";
        $code .= "\t */\n";
        $code .= "\tpublic function delete(\$id){\n";
        $code .= "\t\treturn parent::delete(\$id);\n";
        $code .= "\t}\n\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code for an insert method stub.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for the method stub.
     */
    private function get_method_stub_insert(){
        $code  = "\t/**\n";
        $code .= "\t * Override the insert method found in the base class.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param array \$parms An array of data, probably the \$_POST array.\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param bool \$get_insert_id A flag indicating if we should get the autoincrement value of the record just created.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @return bool TRUE if a record was successfully inserted into the table, FALSE otherwise.\n";
        $code .= "\t */\n";
        $code .= "\tpublic function insert(\$parms, \$get_insert_id = FALSE){\n";
        $code .= "\t\treturn parent::insert(\$parms, \$get_insert_id);\n";
        $code .= "\t}\n\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the code for an update method stub.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for the method stub.
     */
    private function get_method_stub_update(){
        $code  = "\t/**\n";
        $code .= "\t * Override the update method found in the base class.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param array &\$parms An array of key=>value pairs - most likely the \$_POST array.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @param integer \$limit The number of records to update. Defaults to NULL.\n";
        $code .= "\t *\n";
        $code .= "\t * @return bool TRUE if a record was successfully updated, FALSE otherwise.\n";
        $code .= "\t */\n";
        $code .= "\tpublic function update(\$parms, \$limit = NULL){\n";
        $code .= "\t\treturn parent::update(\$parms, \$limit);\n";
        $code .= "\t}\n\n";
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Create method stubs for create, delete and update.
     * 
     * @return string The PHP code for these stubs.
     */
    private function get_method_stubs(){
        $code = $this->get_method_stub_delete();
        $code .= $this->get_method_stub_insert();
        $code .= $this->get_method_stub_update();
        return $code;
    }

    private function get_properties(){
        $code = '';
        if (count($this->columns)){
            foreach ($this->columns AS $index => $col){
                $code .= "\t/**\n";
                if (NULL !== $col['text']){
                    $code .= "\t * $col[text]\n";
                }else{
                    $code .= "\t * Description\n";
                }
                $code .= "\t * @var ". $col['type'];
                if (NULL !== $col['length']){
                    $code .= " ($col[length]";
                    if (NULL !== $col['decimal']){
                        $code .= ",$col[decimal]";
                    }
                    $code .= ")";
                }
                $code .= "\n\t */\n";
                $temp_name = str_replace('#', '_', $col['name']);
                $code .= "\tpublic \$$temp_name;\n\n";
            }
        }
        return $code;
    }
}
?>
```

and here's a simple page to use it:

```
<?php
/**
 * @license GPLv3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)
 * @version 1.0.0_20130220000000
 */

require_once('db_code_generator.php');

$table_type = array();
$table_type['db2'] = 'DB2/400 (db2)';
$table_type['mssql'] = 'Microsoft SQL Server (mssql)';
$table_type['mysql'] = 'MySQL (mysql)';
$table_type['pgsql'] = 'PostGRESQL (pgsql)';
$table_type['sqlite'] = 'SQLite (sqlite)';

$database = (isset($_POST['database'])) ? $_POST['database'] : 'my_database';
$host = (isset($_POST['host'])) ? $_POST['host'] : 'localhost';
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : 'root';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$table = (isset($_POST['table'])) ? $_POST['table'] : '';
$type = (isset($_POST['type'])) ? $_POST['type'] : 'mysql';

$library = (isset($_POST['library'])) ? $_POST['library'] : 'LIBRARY';
$file = (isset($_POST['file'])) ? $_POST['file'] : 'STATES';
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>
<div class="data_input">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset class="top">
            <legend>Code Generator</legend>
            <label for="host">Hostname or IP:
            <input id="host" maxlength="32" name="host" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the database host name" type="text" value="<?php echo $host; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

            <label for="username">Username:
            <input id="username" maxlength="32" name="username" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the database username" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

            <label for="password">Password:
            <input id="password" maxlength="32" name="password" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the database password" type="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

            <label for="type">Type:
            <select id="type" name="type" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>">
                <?php
                foreach ($table_type AS $key=>$value){
                    echo('<option ');
                    if ($key == $type){
                        echo 'selected="selected" ';
                    }
                    echo 'value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            </label>
            <br />

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="top">
            <legend>PostGRESQL/MSSQL/MySQL Parameters</legend>

            <label for="database">Database:
            <input id="database" maxlength="100" name="database" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the database name" type="text" value="<?php echo $database; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

            <label for="table">Table:
            <input id="table" maxlength="100" name="table" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the table name" type="text" value="<?php echo $table; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="top">
            <legend>DB2 Parameters</legend>

            <label for="library">Library:
            <input id="library" maxlength="10" name="library" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the library name" type="text" value="<?php echo $library; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

            <label for="file">Physical File:
            <input id="file" maxlength="10" name="file" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" title="Enter the file name" type="text" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="bottom">
            <button tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>" type="submit">Generate!</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['host'])){
    if ('db2' == $_POST['type']){
        $_POST['database'] = strtoupper($_POST['library']); // Library
        $_POST['table'] = strtoupper($_POST['file']); // Physical file
        $_POST['host'] = 'db2_host';
        $_POST['username'] = 'db2_username';
        $_POST['password'] = 'db2_password';
    }
    $object = new db_code_generator($_POST['database'], $_POST['table'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['host'], $_POST['type']);
    echo('<textarea rows="75" style="margin-left : 50px; width : 90%;" onfocus="select()">'. $object->get_code() .'</textarea>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Darn fricking cool. Could you also share the base_mysql class?

Comment: @Grynn - the `base_mysql` class is over 700 lines long and it's parent class (`base`) is about 650 lines long. I'd be happy to e-mail them to you or something.

Comment: email would be awesome (vishal.doshi@gmail.com) or perhaps you could just paste it to gist.github.com. I'd be happy to make a github or whatever project from your code (attributed to you of course) - so it's maintainable...

Comment: @Grynn - e-mail has been sent.

Comment: Hi, I ll be glad to receive this @  clashnco@gmail.com

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO - I'm sorry, I no longer have this source code.

Comment: Thank you :) . And you @Grynn ??

Answer (score 6):

I understand you're looking for a ORM kind of a thing.

hope this helps

http://www.doctrine-project.org/

http://propelorm.org/

Answer (score 5):

Try this
https://github.com/rcarvello/mysqlreflection

A useful utility I built for the Object Relation Mapping of MySQL databases.

The utility generates automatically PHP classes for any tables of a given database schema.

The package is extracted from my personal PHP Web MVC Framework.

Answer (score 3):

What about [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)? It does exactly what you say and you get a beastly good framework to go with it.

symfony 'compiles' classes for you based on a data model that you supply. It will make sure that compiled classes and MySQL database structure are in sync.

This approach is favorable over a `Reflection` based approach as it's simply too slow.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, [Rafael Rocha](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5357-PHP-Generate-code-to-access-MySQL-records-as-objects.html) shares code [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5357-PHP-Generate-code-to-access-MySQL-records-as-objects.html).

Still, I strongly **propose to use an ORM**. Transforming MySQL structure back to a database-abstraction layer is anything but good...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Doctrine is what you need.

1. **Run a command, and you get all your tables' metadata in XML or YML format**(choice is yours)

   $ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
2. Once you generate the Metadata, **command Doctrine to import the schema to build related entity classes you need. You will find all GET and SET functionality**(read **SELECT**, **UPDATE** and **INSERT**) inside.

   1.$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import Bundle annotation

   2.$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Bundle

   [Read details with Example here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Comment: "There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:mapping" namespace. "

Answer (score 1):

[Fat free framework](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree) allows you to work with existing tables using code like:

```
$user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'users');
// or $user=new DB\Mongo\Mapper($db,'users');
// or $user=new DB\Jig\Mapper($db,'users');
$user->userID='jane';
$user->password=md5('secret');
$user->visits=0;
$user->save();
```

The code above creates new record in *users* table

Answer (score 1):

I have written a PHP code which will automatically detect all the databases in MYSQL database, on selecting any of the database all of its related tables are loaded. You can select all the tables or any respective table to generate the Modal Class.

The following is the link to my repository

https://github.com/channaveer/EntityGenerator

This will automatically create Entity folder and dump all the entity class into that folder.

NOTE - Currently only supported for MYSQL

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make itout on your on. Every project and requirement of Model Code is different in my opinion. Two mysql queries will keep you in ease.

1. `SHOW TABLES FROM db_NAME //this gives the table listing, so its Master Looper`
2. `DESC tbl_name //detail query that fetches column information of given table`

`DESC tbl_name` will give Field, Type, Null, Key, Default and Extra Columns.

e.g. values seperated in pipes (|):

Id | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

I followed these to make Model, controller and Viewer files supporting CRUD operation in Codeigniter 2 way back. It worked just fine.

Comment: I'd rather generate the basics automatically and manipulate what I have after

Comment: yes exactly basic CRUD are always similar if you have standards already established. I guess my lines were unclear but point is, those two queries will give you the table column info and this can be utilized to generate MVC classes and files out of it.